# hbase shell : human readable vs binary keys/values

Tags: hbase

While exploring my hbase data using `hbase shell` and `scan 'mytable', {LIMIT => 10}` , i see that some keys and values are shown in hex e.g. `\x00\x00\x00&\x00\x10&\x18\x01\xECGW\x1AW_\x0A\x82.\x94\xC9\xFE>U\xCC` while others are human readable strings e.g. `file_xyz` .

The schema has been defined identically for both tables. Since HBase only has bytes data type, how is it deciding to show the data differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data contain only ASCII bytes, `hbase shell` displays a string. See also [What are the non-hex characters in HBase Shell RowKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353013/what-are-the-non-hex-characters-in-hbase-shell-rowkey/42375708)

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense. I have been expecting that the complete value will be displayed in hex digits even if some of the digits are out of ASCII space.